# save the data under the currentuser in the datafirebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I create a web-page where users can log in and update their profiles,

[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W0SN.jpg)

but the button doesn't work, it doesnt save the data in the current user in the firebase, like the about and userImg [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ZGA.jpg)

*bellow is my code*

html:

```
<form class="Email-change">
    <p class="text-typ">Email:</p>
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="line">
    <p class="text-typ">Username:</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.displayName">
    <p class="text-typ">About:</p>
    <input type="text" id="aboutMsg" ng-model="user.About">
    <br>
    <button class="change" id="aboutSubmit" onclick="updateAbout()">Change 
information</button>
</form>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('SignUpController', ['$scope', '$location', '$firebaseAuth', 
function ($scope, $location, $firebaseAuth) {

$scope.signUp = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    $firebaseAuth().$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, 
  user.password)
        .then(function (fireUser) {
            if (fireUser) {


                var theUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                theUser.updateProfile({
                    displayName: user.username

                }).then(function () {

                    //om det är ok

                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);

                });
                firebase.database().ref('/users/' + fireUser.uid).set({
                    username: user.username

                });

                $location.path('/');

            }

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            $scope.error = err.message;
        });

};


}]);
```

java:

```
`function updateAbout(){
alert('it works');
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users');


firebaseRef.child("About").set("I Love dancing");
console.log("I love dancing");
}`
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't save, can you put a breakpoint in your javascript to see if you actually make firebase api call or view network calls in chrome? what error do you get? shouldn't `updateAbout` be defined on `$scope`, and change call to `ng-click` in html

Comment: dosent save the data in the users in the firebas, it saves the data in the users and not in the current user. I will try to call it by ng-click and defiend it by &scope by I dont think that it is the problem because the function sends information to the firebase and it saves the information in the firebase but not in the current user

Comment: look-around-89d60
users
1az1uGcFp5TO4mcXxAZzOXNrgzD2
username: 
"ikhlaq"
About: 
"I Love dancing"
UserImg: 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..."
ZGGtfzGGnzXs6sPnmmuuBE2nBfP2
username: 
"Aml Abbas"
mRarzJXZtLSuRovOwoja4aqp9mJ2
q0V3WHbPlPXWtp58bUERWdaTQh13
username: 
"Aml Abbas"
(Here is what it looks like in the firebase, I want to save about in the userid 'currentuser' and not in the users, so the functions works and send the data to the firebase but not in the currentuser what should i do to save information in the currentuser?)